# Objective C protocol reference as instance variable in C++ class

Tags: c++, objective-c, protocols

Isn't it possible to have a reference to an Objective C protocol inside a C++ class? The

```
(id)<B2ContactListener> _B2ContactListener;
```

line results in two errors:

'*Expected ; at end of declaration list*'

and

'*C++ requires a type specifier for all declarations*'.

Here's the code.

B2_ContactListener.mm:

```
#import "Box2D.h"
#import "B2_ContactListener.h"

class ContactListener : public b2ContactListener
{
private:
  (id)<B2ContactListener> _B2ContactListener; // ERRORs

public:
  //Methods
};
```

B2_ContactListener.h:

```
#import "B2_Contact.h"

@protocol B2ContactListener
-(void)B2BeginContact: (B2Contact*) contact;
@end
```

I'm using the current XCode compiler BTW.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drop the parentheses:

```
id<B2ContactListener> _B2ContactListener;
```

That should work.

Another thing you may want to consider is making it an `NSObject *` instead, so you can invoke methods inherited from `NSObject` without having to cast.

Comment: No, don't make it `NSObject *`. The protocol should instead extend the `NSObject` protocol

Comment: @newacct Sure, but then you wouldn't be able to invoke methods inherited from `NSObject`. Sometimes you can make assumptions, sometimes you can't.